# Having trouble sending email through local host (XAMPP)

Tags: php, xampp, localhost, sendmail, sendmail.exe

I followed the XAMPP documentation on setting up sendmail.exe. I added

```
sendmail_path = “\”C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\” -t”
```

to the php.ini file and

```
smtp_server=ssl://smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=465
smtp_ssl=auto
error_logfile=error.log
auth_username=[myemail]@gmail.com
auth_password=[my password]
```

to the sendmail.ini file. I then created the following test per the XAMPP documentation

```
<?php
$to = '[myemail]@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Hello from XAMPP!';
$message = 'This is a test';
$headers = "From: [myemail]@gmail.com\r\n";
if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
   echo "SUCCESS";
} else {
   echo "ERROR";
}
?>
```

I get the SUCCESS echo, but nothing shows up in my inbox. Am I missing something?

Comment: why don't you use phpMailer ?

Comment: Have your tried send mail without **from** header ? 
If you set from header other than your own email address, gmail may block sending mail.